# Electron app with electron-updater built with "npm run make" does not work

Tags: npm, electron, electron-forge

I have an Electron application which uses "electron-updater" package. The app works when running from VScode. But if building the app with "npm run make", it failed to load when double clicking the app due to this error:

```
Uncaught Exception: Error: Cannot find module 'builder-util-runtime'
```

This line in main.js causes problem:

```
const { autoUpdater } = require("electron-updater");
```

If removing this line, the app works from VSCode debugger. "npm run make" build app also works! It proves this line causes the problem.

Build environment (mac):

```
% node -v
  v18.13.0
% npm -v
  8.19.3
% electron --version
  v22.0.0
```

electron-updater is installed in above environment, which is installed after electron is installed:

```
npm install electron-updater
```

Package.json

```
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "electron-updater": "^5.3.0",
  ...

"devDependencies": {
  ...
  "electron": "^22.0.0",
  ...
```

It is noticed, directory "builder-util-runtime/out" with content is installed in "node_modules" after eletron-updater is installed. "builder-util-runtime" is not installed manually.

On mac, checking the built app file by browsing (right click the app) "myapp/Show Package Content/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/builder-util-runtime". This directory is empty, which is the reason of the failure to load the app.

I tried manually install "builder-util-runtime". Regardless what's been done to "builder-util-runtime" in development environment, the "npm run make" creates this directory in distribution package without content which is root cause of the problem.

How to fix it so that the distribution package has "builder-util-runtime" and content?

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem and I use `yarn` but not `pnpm` then the problem disappear

Comment: Thank you for sharing your experience. I used yarn to install 'electron-updater'. I believe I still have the problem. If possible, can you give some details?

Comment: In fact, I deleted `node_modules`, run `yarn install` directly to switch my package manager from 'pnpm' to 'yarn'. Maybe you can try